# How to get autofill using a modified \ref command working in Overleaf?

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, renewcommand

I have a MacBook and a Windows desktop PC and I regularly use both Machines to edit tex documents on overleaf.

In the overleaf doc, in order to normalize my figure, section and citation referencing I use the following commands in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure \ref{#1}} %reference figures
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Eq.\ \ref{#1}} %reference equations
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section \ref{#1}} %reference sections
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter \ref{#1}} %reference chapters
\newcommand{\rref}[1]{Ref.\ \cite{#1}} %reference citation
```

So that I can use the same referencing style throughout and easily edit it if a journal requires a certain format.

The problem is that if I use the Mac, the autofill does not work and I'm forced to write

`\ref{}`

and then add f,e,s,c, or r between '' and 'r'. This isn't particularly challenging but I have hand issues so this can add significantly to my writing process and force me to take more frequent breaks.

If I use the windows machine it works just fine (but it is a desktop so I don't always have that option).

I use safari on the Mac but I just checked Chrome and it also does not work. I use opera on my PC.